# How to jQuery select all links on a page that are NOT contained within a certain div

Tags: jquery, arrays, selector, inverse

Suppose I have product links on a page, some products are within a recommendation div:

```
<a href="some_url?pid=abc"><img src ... ></a>
<a href="some_url?pid=abc">ABC Product Name...</a>

<a href="some_url?pid=def">
 .... more product links

<div class="recommendations">
  <a href="some_url?pid=uvw"> ...
  <a href="some_url?pid=xyz"> ...
</div>
```

I need to construct unique list of pids for recommended and non-recommended urls like this:

```
 recommended_pids = ["uvw","xyz"];
 non_recommened_pids = ["abc","def"];
```

I know I can git the list of all pid on a page like this:

```
 $('a[href*="pid="]').each(function() {
   //get just the pid part
   var link = this.href;
   var pid = link.split('pid=')[1].split('&')[0];
   pids.push(pid);
 });
```

And I can get the list of recommended pids on a page using selector like this:

```
$('div.recommended a[href*="pid="]')
```

Sort and uniq each array then subtract all elements then do array subtraction to get the list of non-recommended pids.

But is there a way to use other jQuery filters to get the list of pids NOT contained within the recommended div without resorting to writing an array subtract function?

Comment: You may have to verify, but $('a:not(.recommendations a)') should do the trick i believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's always `.filter()`:

```
var $pidLinks = $('a[href*="pid="]');
// recommended links
$pidLinks.filter('div.recommendations > a');
// non-recommended links
$pidLinks.filter(':not(div.recommendations > a)');
```

[Somewhat gratuitous jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/QdtTe/1/)

For what it's worth, @Jayendra's solution is simpler and probably better, *unless* you need to get both lists - in which case I believe that using `.filter()` should have better performance if you cache the original selection of all links.

Answer (score 2):

Use not

```
$("a:not(.recommendations a)").each(function(index){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the each function you could do this:

```
if( $(this).parents(".recommendations").length ) {

    recommended_pids.push(pid);

} else {

    non_recommened_pids.push(pid);

}
```